# swift3 thread1:Signal SIGABRT,Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException'

Tags: ios, swift3, xcode8

Everything is fine but when I click on the tableView and went to the thread:

```
thread1:Signal SIGABRT, '[<UIViewController 0x7fc3c0c0b730> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key lastName.'
```

`AppDelegate.swift`, and the error went on the line:`class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate`

```
import UIKit  

@UIApplicationMain  
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {  

    var window: UIWindow?  

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {  
        // Override point for customization after application launch.  
        return true  
    }  

    func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {  
    // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
    // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and invalidate graphics rendering callbacks. Games should use this method to pause the game.
}

func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
    // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
}

func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Called as part of the transition from the background to the active state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
}

func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
}

func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
}
}
```

`DetailsViewController.swift`, after click the tableview it should go to detailView and show the details of the data in the table

```
import UIKit

class DetailsViewController: UIViewController {

    var st:Student?


    @IBOutlet weak var stName: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var lastName: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var phoneNumber: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var studentId: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        stName.text=st?.fName;
        lastName.text=st?.lName;
        phoneNumber.text=st?.phoneNum;
        studentId.text=st?.id;

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

}
```

`TableViewController.swift`, and one more question, What's `@IBAction func myUnwindAction(segue:UIStoryboardSegue)`about?

```
import UIKit

class TableTabViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate {


    @IBOutlet weak var dataTable: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet var barButton   : UIBarButtonItem?


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        dataTable.delegate=self;
        dataTable.dataSource=self;

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

    }


    @IBAction func myUnwindAction(segue: UIStoryboardSegue)
    {

        if let temp = segue.source as? NewStudentViewController{
            if (temp.exitBool != true){
                StudentDataBase.instance.addStudent(st: temp.st!);
                dataTable.reloadData();
            }
        }

    }



    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return StudentDataBase.instance.getNumberOfStudents();
    }


    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell=UITableViewCell();
        cell.textLabel?.text=StudentDataBase.instance.getStudentByIndex(index: indexPath.row).getFullName();
        return cell;
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "details", sender: StudentDataBase.instance.getStudentByIndex(index: indexPath.row));
    }


    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any? ){
        if let detailsController=segue.destination as? DetailsViewController{
            detailsController.st=sender as? Student;
        }


    }


    @IBAction func editTableView (_ sender:UIBarButtonItem)
    {
        if dataTable.isEditing{
            //listTableView.editing = false;
            dataTable.setEditing(false, animated: true);
            barButton?.style = UIBarButtonItemStyle.plain;
            barButton?.title = "Edit";
            //listTableView.reloadData();
        }
        else{
            //listTableView.editing = true;
            dataTable.setEditing(true, animated: true);
            barButton?.title = "Done";
            barButton?.style =  UIBarButtonItemStyle.done;
            //listTableView.reloadData();
        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
    {
        if editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.delete{
            if(StudentDataBase.instance.deleteStudent(ids: StudentDataBase.instance.getStudentByIndex(index: indexPath.row).id!))
            {
                self.editTableView(barButton!);
                dataTable.reloadData();
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You have incorrectly set the custom view controller subclass in Interface Builder. (Perhaps, you renamed the class?) So it falls back to the parent `UIViewController`.
Notice the "Unknown class" warning in the debugger output.
The crash happens due to an outlet set up between a `PhoneNumber` property and a view, however since the controller subclass is not set properly, the system attempts to find the `PhoneNumber` outlet on `UIViewController` and crashes.

To fix, set the correct subclass name in Interface Builder.

Comment: I renamed the project, and before that I didn't see any problems. I checked the DetaislViewController and found the outlet phoneNumber was not connected, fixed, but still have the problem.

Comment: If you renamed the project, make sure to set the "Module" correctly. It's right under the class name of the controller in Interface Builder.

Comment: hello, as I fixed the problem of phonenumber as I didn't have a proper connection between phonenumber and a view. after that, it came to another problem on lastName, could you please tell me how to do?